# Como delimitar as colunas de uma matriz no Julia

Tags: julia

Tenho uma matrix 4:3 e gostaria de pegar somente 2:3.

É possivel delimitar usando o comando DelimitedFiles?
Como devo usar?

```
Q = convert(Matrix, ACT[2:3]) #Gostaria de omitir o 2:3
```

Comment: Olá Raquel.
Por que não cria uma função que retorna somente as linhas e colunas que deseja dessa matriz?
Por exemplo, num algoritmo hipotético, temos `m = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]` percorrendo a matriz num _loop for_   
`for i in matrix  
 for j in matrix  
 if (j != row AND J != col )  
 print(matrix[i][j]`  

se `row = 0` e `col = 0 ` 

temos

`[[6,7,8],[10,11,12],[14,15,16];`

Comment: Oi Felipe, muito obrigada pela ajuda. Fiz exatamente como vc postou e não funcionou, apareceu isso: especificação de iteração inválida. Não sei se na hora que tentei colocar os meus dados fiz algo errado, pq o "for" que vc postou faz todo o sentido rsrsrs

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta e colocar um exemplo da matrix 4:3 e como seria a 2:3 que você precisa na saída? Talvez, facilite para responder :-)

Comment: Oi Gomeiro, obrigada pela sugestão. Tenho um dataframe extraído de um .CSV com 4x3. gostaria de visualizar apenas os números que estão nesse dataframe.                                                                                                                       Saída que preciso.     87  0                                                                                                                                                
                                   0    11

Comment: Vamos ver se eu entendi...o DataFrame tem 4 colunas e 3 linhas e você precisa extrair todos elementos que estão nas 2 primeiras colunas (e 3 linhas)? É isso?